# How to calculate matrix rotation

Tags: matrices, matlab, rotations

> Given the following rotation matrix
>
> $$\left[
>    \begin{matrix}
>    -1/3 &  2/3 & -2/3 \\
>     2/3 & -1/3 & -2/3 \\
>    -2/3 & -2/3 & -1/3 \\
>    \end{matrix}
> \right]$$
>
> what is the corresponding axis-angle representation assuming the angle is restricted to [0, $\pi$]?

How can I solve this question without MatLab and using MatLab?

Comment: Do you know how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix?

Comment: No. I didn't lean it yet.

Comment: [Rotation matrix - Conversion from and to axis-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis-angle).

Comment: It's not a rotation matrix. For starters, a rotation matrix is never symmetric. Is there a typo?

Comment: @IlikeSerena: it is clearly an orthogonal matrix, since its columns have unit norm and are pairwise orthogonal. It is also a symmetric matrix, true, and so? For instance, a matrix encoding a reflection is both orthogonal and symmetric.

Comment: A lot of people restrict their definition of rotation matrices to be orthogonal matricies with determinant 1 (and consider those with determinant -1 to be improper rotations or rotations with a reflection).

Comment: @IlikeSerena it's rotation matrix because M*transpose(M) = transpose(M)*M = I and det(M) = 1

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio as far as I know, the axis-angle representation only works with proper rotations (which this matrix is not). Axis-angle results from the exponentiation of $\mathfrak{so}_3$ and defining the rotation vector to be $\mathbf{r} = \theta\mathbf{e}$, where $\theta$ is the principle angle and $\mathbf{e}$ is the invariant axis. If you can point to a resource which parameterizes improper rotations via axis-angle, I would be much obliged...

Comment: @ALB: this matrix **is** a proper rotation. It is a rotation of an angle equal to $\pi$ around some axis.

Comment: My apologies. Indeed, a rotation matrix can be symmetric iff $\theta = 0$ or $\theta=\pi$, in which case we either have the identity matrix or a reflection in a line, which is what we have.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio OK. Then of course you're right. Parenthetically, I wish I had checked myself, rather than falsely assumed from your post that you had and it ended up being a proper rotation + reflection, which you could also claim is a 'rotation' but in a more abstract sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick: if an orthogonal matrix represent a rotation around some axis with amplitude $\theta$, such a matrix is similar to
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
but the [**trace**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of a matrix is left unchanged by matrix conjugation, hence in your case
$$1+2\cos\theta = -\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3} = -1 $$
gives $\theta=\pm\pi$.
A second trick is to notice that your matrix is [both orthogonal and symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation), so its eigenvalues belong to $\{-1,1\}$. The trace is $-1$, hence the spectrum is $\{-1,-1,1\}$. The rotation axis is given by the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, hence it is given by $(-1,-1,1)$.

Comment: You find the eigenvalue and eigenvector, but how to find the corresponding axis-angle representation?

Comment: @furstmartins: I gave you the rotation axis and the angle, what else do you need?

Comment: my apologies. It's not clear to me. Why did you use z-axis in this case? The question didn't define what axis we need to use. You finded the eigenvector and could you say that is it the axis-angle representation?

Comment: @furstmartins: there is no $z$-axis in my answer. The rotation axis is given by the vector $(-1,-1,1)$, as written.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, without making use of similarity, eigenvalues, or eigenvectors.

If we pick a point $\mathbf x$ on the axis, its image must be the same point on the axis. So we can find the axis by solving $A\mathbf x=\mathbf x$, where $A$ is the given matrix. Solving it we'll find $(-1,-1,1)$ or some multiple thereof.

Once we have the axis, we can pick a vector $\mathbf y$ perpendicular to it, e.g. $(1,-1,0)$, and calculate its image. The angle between $\mathbf y$ and $A\mathbf y$ is the rotation angle. More specifically, their dot product is $\mathbf y\cdot A\mathbf y = \|\mathbf y\|^2 \cos \theta$, from which we can solve $\theta$. If we do, we'll find $\theta=\pi$.